# How can I run benchmarks in Guava

Tags: java, guava

Guava has `guava-tests` subdirectory that contains a `benchmark` directory -- https://github.com/google/guava/tree/master/guava-tests/benchmark/com/google/common.

How can I run this benchmark suite?

Comment: I know it's weird to hear that, but don't. they use `caliper` for perf tests and `jmh` is a lot better and more correct.

Comment: Generally you just run them like any other binary.  I've never had to worry about it -- if I load them into my IDE, I can just run the class.

Comment: Is there a way to run this benchmark suite locally via some command line?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.